# Nokia 929 Windows Phone

Tags: sync

How do I download my Nokia 929 Windows phone's "People" contacts out of my phone and then transfer them to my PC with Windows 10. I have tried to sync account but I find that under my "email+accounts" that my Outlook.com always states, "Not up to date", even though I have just update both my phone and pc. Any suggestions???

Comment: What type of account is this (Hotmail/Gmail/Exchange/etc.)? Do you know which *version* of Windows Phone you're running (8.1? 10?)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[contacts + messages backup](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/contacts-message-backup/9nblgggz57gm)** app Microsoft.

The application enables you to backup your contacts into a **.vcf** file on your Micro SD Card or phone's storage, which you can then transfer off or copy to your PC, and then open it from there to access and save your contacts.

[image] [image]